# Can I have Flash Builder compile different files in Debug and Release mode?

Tags: compilation, flash-builder, release

I'd like to have some variables set to different values depending if I'm compiling in Debug or in Release mode: is that possible?

Including different files or something like a `#DEFINE` would be fine either way.

---

**edit**

In case it wasn't clear, this have to happen automatically: if I have to change something by hand every time I compile, it's completely pointless. The **whole** point of this question is **exactly *NOT*** having to do it.

- I compile `DEBUG` --> I have [x] set
- I compile `RELEASE` --> I have [y] set

---

Another way to see it is: from the program itself, **can I detect** if it has been compiled in debug or release mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's some code](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/how-to-identify-at-runtime-if-swf-is-in-debug-or-release-mode-build/) which you can use to check the compile mode at runtime:

```
    public static function isDebugBuild() : Boolean
    {
        return new Error().getStackTrace().search(/:[0-9]+]$/m) > -1;
    }

    public static function isReleaseBuild() : Boolean
    {
        return !isDebugBuild();
    }
```

Comment: I've had a look at the documentation you linked, but it doesn't say anything about that. It just says, like @eclps said, you can set those at compile time, but nothing about them being automatically set.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I'm sorry: the **whole** point of the question (sorry if it wasn't clear) is **NOT** to do it by hand. If I have to change it by hand every time, it's completely pointless.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice the "Alternatively", that would be it! I'm trying it, thanks :)

Comment: It is behaving very strangely: if I run it while in Release mode, it "skips" the current main loop to the next main loop call, like if I `return`ed (dunno if it is clear, I find very hard to explain this). Still, this somehow allows me to do it - I'll wait to see if a better way comes, though.

Comment: I saw that behaviour too, it seems to work if you run it in the debug player, but when you run it in the release player then it acts strangely. Sorry I couldn't find a solution to your problem.

Comment: np, this somehow *resembles* a solution. It's so unstable and unpredictable (i.e. *risky*) that in the end I can't really use it in production code, but it's not your fault ;) (ps: edited the post to leave on only the pertaining section, removing the irrelevant one)

Comment: Mh, looks like my edit didn't pass, I wonder why... could you please edit your post to include only the "Alternatively" section?

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a variable into ActionScript using a compile argument. The following would pass in a constant named 'debugging' within the 'CONFIG' namespace:

```
-define=CONFIG::debugging,true
```

You can than create a conditional in ActionScript:

```
CONFIG::debugging {
    // Perform debug code
}
```

Also note there is a debug flag to enable/disable compiling debug information:

```
-debug=true|false
```

Comment: Uh? And where do I configure the different compila arguments for debug and release?

Comment: I've been just looking for a way to access the value of the compiler setting -debug=true|false during compile time, like you can with custom CONFIG settings. Seems like it should be simple, but so far, no joy... This would allow, e.g., removal of debug code from a release build simply by pressing the run button vs the debug button...